# using or excecution of sleep in setOnclicklistner function

Tags: java, android

I code a program which I expected to perform follwing action sequentially onclick the button:
    1.Display the text(eg: "abc") in textview.
    2.sleep for sometime(eg:2000).
    3.finally it has to change the text(eg: "xyz") in textview.
for that i try the below code. when I run this, first it sleep for 2000 millisecond and display "xyz", It doesnot displaying "abc"...
(*** I noticed that sleep will excecuting first inside the setOnclickListner()function then only rest of the code are excecuting ***)
please help me to perform the action in sequence...

If my question is silly please excuse as I was new to this....

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


Button b1;
TextView tv;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tv.setText("abc");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            tv.setText("xyz");
        }
    });
          }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Handler.postDelayed` instead of `Thread.sleep` which freeze main UI Thread for `2000`. Do same using `Handler` as:

Create Runnable :

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
         tv.setText("xyz");
          mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable); 
        }
    };
```

call `Handler.postDelayed` on Button click :

```
mHandler = new Handler();
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tv.setText("abc");

            mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);  
        }
    });
```